# Assembly: Outputting variables, OS dependent?, Executing

Tags: assembly, x86-64, windows-7-x64

I am trying to learn some Assembly after we talked about it a little in class. I am trying to translate a basic java program to find a Fibonacci number into assembly and I think I got the logic right, but my friend tells me that it might not work on my Windows 7 64bits computer because ASM is different depending on your OS ( :O Is he serious? )

Here is my code:

```
SECTION .data   

Var2: resd 3
Var5: resd 4
Var1: db 10
Var3: db 1
Var4: db 1

SECTION .text   
global main
main:

MOV Var2,0

Loop1:
  ADD Var2,1
  MOV Var5,Var3
  ADD Var3,Var4
  MOV Var4,Var5
  CMP Var2,Var1
  JE Fin
  JP Loop1

Fin:
Put printing in here.
```

2/ Is there something similar to System.out.print in ASM?

3/ How exactly do I execut it once I figure that out? I got RadASM but I can't seem to run my code through it. How do I execute the ASM program once done ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Almost every binary executable program is dependent on the OS, independently of the programming language it's written in. Programs written in assembly are no exception. Don't confuse bytecode (eg. Java) with native processor code (eg. x86-64). And of course you have to follow the syntax of the programming language you use. Your program will not assemble on most assemblers due to the syntax errors related to memory addressing.
2. In protected mode OSes such as Windows 7 you have to use your OS API for printing.
3. You execute a program written in assembly as any other binary executable. First you write the code, then you assemble and link it, and then execute. Just like any other binary executable. The difference with higher-level compiled languages is that assembling is a lot simpler task for the assembler (the program) to do than compiling of higher-level source code for the compiler.

In x86-64 assembly you can't move from memory address directly to another. You have to first move the one of the general registers of the processor, and then from that register to another memory address. However, there are instructions that move from memory to memory too, such as `movsb`, `movsw`, `movsd` and `movsq`, but to get started with, it's easier to learn them later.

It's not clear what you want the size of the variables to be, as you use `db` for some, and `resd` for others. If you want that all `Var1`, `Var2`, `Var3`, `Var4`, `Var5` to be bytes, then it should be for example:

```
Var2: db 3
Var5: db 4
Var1: db 10
Var3: db 1
Var4: db 1
```

And if you want them to be for example dwords, replace every `db` with `dd`. `resd` means reserve dwords, to reserve bytes you should use `resb`.

You must know the size of the operands in assembly. Assembler does not make the decisions for you.

Assuming all variables above are bytes (`db`, 8 bits each), the loop could be something like (NASM/YASM syntax):

```
Loop1:
    ADD [Var2],byte 1

    MOV al,[Var3]
    MOV [Var5],al

    mov al,Var4
    ADD Var3,al

    mov al,[Var5]
    MOV Var4,al

    mov al,[Var1]
    CMP Var2,al
    JE Fin
    JP Loop1
```

And if you want them to be dwords (`dd`, 32 bits each):

```
Loop1:
    ADD [Var2],dword 1

    MOV eax,[Var3]
    MOV [Var5],eax

    mov eax,Var4
    ADD Var3,eax

    mov eax,[Var5]
    MOV Var4,eax

    mov eax,[Var1]
    CMP Var2,eax
    JE Fin
    JP Loop1
```

Comment: I left some as resd because I don't have their values set as it is. I am including the answer you gave in the first post and editing it accordingly.

Comment: Once the program reaches its end, how do I print out the content of Var5 ? Like have it show the output?

Comment: @Niehm I rolled back your edit, because copying answer to question causes the answer to lose its meaning for people trying to solve same kind of problems in the future.

Comment: In case of bytes, normally you use `resb` (`resd` is for dwords). And anyway it does not normally make sense to add some value to undefined value with `ADD Var2,1` (if `Var2` is undefined).

Comment: I don't have Windows, but see [this link](http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?PHPSESSID=786dd40408172108b65a5a36b09c88c0&topic=16292.0) for Windows x86-64 assembly Hello world, to check out the printing and exiting code.

Comment: Ok I understand why you need to set before adding to it, but will my loop still execute 10 times? Meaning if I start var2 at 1 and add 1 byte does that mean the value of var2 is now 2 and after going through it will end up being equal to var1 that was initialized at 10 ?

Comment: I looked at your link, I understand it after some research on some code I didn't know, but what about the libraries that are imported ? Where exactly is that from and where does it go exactly directories wise ?